# VSTS. Copy File task is not creating folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have continuous integration setup for the web app project in VSTS. Thing is I need to copy some folder, let's call it "Libs"from NuGet package location to the bin folder of the web app. I employed VSTS "Copy Files" task for it. After couple of failings I've figured out how to properly(at least I think so) setup the task, but, alas, folder is not appearing in artifact zip file and I don't understand why.

"Copy File" task runs successfully. But when I click "Artifacts" button on successful build and look inside "drop" container web app zip file does not contain "Libs" folder under bin directory, as I expected it to be.

> What am I doing wrong?

Here is line from my "Copy File" task during the build:

> 2018-05-22T19:24:37.5090638Z Copying
>   D:\a\1\s\WebApp\packages\ImportantPackage.1.0.0.0\lib\net461\Libs\SomeLib.dll
>   to D:\a\1\a\bin\Libs\SomeLib.dll

Here is how I actually setup "Copy File" task:
[image]

Here is how Publish task looks like:

[image]

Comment: What does your Publish Artifacts step look like?

Comment: @DanielMann Please take a look. I've posted my Publish task.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your Source Folder: `...\ImortantPackage.1.0.0.0\...` is probably supposed to be `...\ImportantPackage.1.0.0.0\...`.

Try selecting the source folder from the explorer by clicking the three dots next to the folder path and selecting the correct folder.

Comment: No, that's not typo issue. Already tried that. Clicking is not a remedy either, unfortunately.